# Get tick values of colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

How can I extract the currently displayed ticks of a `matplotlib` colorbar as a list? With this example I should get the the list with floats`[-0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6]`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(100,100))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get ticklabels of colorbar axis (it is may be x or y axes):

```
cb=plt.colorbar()
for t in cb.ax.get_yticklabels(): print(t.get_text())
```

Or

```
ticks = [float(t.get_text().replace('−','-')) for t in cb.ax.get_yticklabels()]
print (ticks)
```

In my locale minus is a little bit different and I replace it with usual minus symbol (or it matplotlib behavior).

Output

```
[-0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6]
```

Comment: I had to modify the replace with `.replace(u'\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-')` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

In version [2.1](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5792/) of matplotlib `colorbar.get_ticks()` method was introduced.